# How can I get a value from mongodb to an angularjs controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, mean-stack, meanjs

I am new to Web Development and started out with a MEAN-Stack (Mongo, Express, Angular, Node).

**In short**, I would like to get a value from mongo into my angular controller to use multiple values from mongo in a formula like this:

```
value11*value12 + value21*value22 ...etc
```

**My Problem in more detail:**

1. I already wrote with a fieldset some data into mongo:

HTML Snippet

```
<fieldset>
<rzslider rz-slider-model="value11"
          rz-slider-options="slider11.options"></rzslider>
<md-slider flex md-discrete ng-model="value12" step="1" min="1 max="100 aria-label="rating"></md-slider
</fieldset>
```

Controller.js Snippet. The rzslider comes from there https://github.com/angular-slider/angularjs-slider
The md-slider from Angular-Material

```
$scope.slider11 = { 
  options: { 
    showTicks: true,
    hidePointerLabels: true,
    hideLimitLabels: true,
    stepsArray: [
      { value: 1, legend: 'Very poor' }
      { value: 2, legend: 'Poor' },
      { value: 3, legend: 'Fair' },
      { value: 4, legend: 'Good' }, 
      { value: 5, legend: 'Very Good' }
    ] 
  }
};
$scope.value12 = 40;
//Create new Article object
var article = new Articles
  value11: this.value11,
  value12: this.value12,
```

At this point everything is working and in mongo the set values get stored.

2. In this second step I would like to get the value from the database
   into a different controller to include them in above mentioned
   formula.  The only thing working so far is to recall the values like
   this in the html view directly:

HTML Snippet

```
{{article.value11 * article.value12}}
```

which works, as far as I understood thanks to a query like below.

Controller snippet

```
// Find a list of Articles
$scope.find = function () {
$scope.articles = Articles.query();
};
```

But ultimately I would like to recall the database values and define them as a new $scope in a controller.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the idea behind the whole MEAN stack and more-or-less the whole frontend/backend idea is that your angular application is the frontend and you need to make a AJAX call to your Node.js service to connect to MongoDB

Think of it like this
`Angular <---AJAX---> Node <------> Mongo`

So the first thing you need is to build a rest service (using the help of the express framework) so something like this would work

```
app.get('/getMongoData', function(req, res, next) {
     //code to get mongo data with Mongoose

     req.json(DataFromMongo); //returns the data in json format
});
```

Here is where you will use your backend code to grab data from the Mongo Database using the [Mongoose package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose) and return send it back using the `req.json()` call which is part of Express

Now that this all work you can call the data from your Angular controller with something like

```
$http.get('/getMongoData').then(function(response) {
      $scope.myMongoData = response.data;       
});
```

NOTE: don't forget to add `$http` to your controller's injection
`app.controller('MyController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) { // code  }]);`

Comment: It worked exactly like you just explained. Thumbs up and thanks for that fast answer :D